# jQuery.ajax fires success on 404 or any other errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

A simple Ajax request via jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php', data: {}, type: 'post', async: false,
    success: function(result, status, XHR){ 
        alert('success:'+XHR.status);
    }, error: function(XHR, status, error){ 
        alert('error:'+XHR.status);
    }
});
```

while `ajax.php` just contains:

```
<?php header('HTTP/1.1 404'); ?>
```

surprisingly alerts `success:404`!
(Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0)

Has a bug been reported for this issue before, or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Besides the Javascript errors in your alerts (you should change "=" to "+"), I see nothing wrong. The code actually alerts "error:404" for me. Windows 7, Chrome and Firefox (latest versions). Have you tested this php function to change the response code: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php?

Comment: @yvanavermaet `=`'s just a mistake and edited. I tested `http_response_code(404);`, but still the same problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

I copy-pasted your code and it works just fine. Outputs "error:404"

test.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php', data: {}, type: 'post', async: false,
    success: function(result, status, XHR){ 
        alert('success:'+XHR.status);
    }, error: function(XHR, status, error){ 
        alert('error:'+XHR.status);
    }
});
</script>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Hello</p>

</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php header('HTTP/1.1 404'); ?>
```

Comment: The code was working before, I'm afraid if that's an unknown issue on my Ubuntu OS. It just happened after a hardware reset due to suddenly unplugged power cable, but I'm not really going to consider it as logical reason. However, my OS and PHP seems damaged!

Comment: @Omid I don't know... I'm using Mint 15 and Firefox 26. Not sure why it would be related to your OS.